# Не по теме, но всё же. Проблема с DNS Cache в Win7

Tags: dns

Доброго всем дня.

Извиняюсь за то, что вопрос не по теме форума, но всё же.

В общем, приобрел домен, направил его на НС-ы своего сервера.

Через пару часов проверил WHOIS - всё направлено нормально, привязалось. 
Пробую перейти - ошибка ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED.

С другого ПК, с телефона и тд - всё нормально, отображает.

В общем, пошла мысль, что вся фигня эта из-за кеша DNS.

Почистил через ipconfig / flushdns, перезагрузил ПК - ноль эмоций.

Попробовал почистить в браузере через chrome://net-internals/#events - опять ноль эмоций. Но там уже показало заодно следующее:

```
7749: HTTP_STREAM_JOB
http://radiance.party/
Start Time: 2015-06-15 18:00:47.616

t=1272 [st=   0] +HTTP_STREAM_JOB  [dt=2253]
                  --> original_url = "http://radiance.party/"
                  --> priority = "HIGHEST"
                  --> url = "http://radiance.party/"
t=1272 [st=   0]   +PROXY_SERVICE  [dt=0]
t=1272 [st=   0]      PROXY_SERVICE_RESOLVED_PROXY_LIST
                      --> pac_string = "DIRECT"
t=1272 [st=   0]   -PROXY_SERVICE
t=1272 [st=   0]   +HOST_RESOLVER_IMPL_REQUEST  [dt=1]
                    --> address_family = 0
                    --> allow_cached_response = true
                    --> host = "radiance.party:80"
                    --> is_speculative = false
t=1273 [st=   1]   -HOST_RESOLVER_IMPL_REQUEST
                    --> net_error = -804 (ERR_DNS_CACHE_MISS)
t=1273 [st=   1]    TCP_CLIENT_SOCKET_POOL_REQUESTED_SOCKET
                    --> host_and_port = "radiance.party:80"
t=1273 [st=   1]   +SOCKET_POOL  [dt=2252]
t=3525 [st=2253]      SOCKET_POOL_BOUND_TO_CONNECT_JOB
                      --> source_dependency = 7752 (CONNECT_JOB)
t=3525 [st=2253]   -SOCKET_POOL
                    --> net_error = -105 (ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED)
t=3525 [st=2253] -HTTP_STREAM_JOB
```

В общем, уже и не знаю, что делать.

Кто что подскажет?

Comment: Какой dns-сервер используете? Что выдает команда `nslookup radiance.party`?

Comment: подождать пока кэш на модеме и у провайдера умрет, и попробовать еще раз.

Comment: @PavelMayorov nslookup отдал айпишники NS-серверов регистратора. Однако в панели НС-ы давно перевязаны на НС-ы своего сервера, ведь с других устройств работает нормально

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Значит, ваша проблема - в кэше на уровне используемого DNS-сервера. Если вы используете сервер провайдера - смените его на гугл-днс. Если используете гугл-днс - смените на сервер провайдера. В общем, найдите такой сервер, который будет отдавать нужный вам адрес.

Ну, или просто подождите, пока у используемого вами сервера не устареет запись об этом домене в кэше.